# React question: how to make the variable in useEffect to be received outside of useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was using the useEffect to receive the a global variable chart1, where inside the hooks I define this variable to a Chart object with some data and attributes. However, the change of the chart1 won't be seen when I do chart1.destroy() outside the hooks like the code below, but it will be seen when I do the same operation inside useEffect. I want to see the change of chart outside the hooks so that the chart will be rendered to canvas by hooks. Is there any way to do that?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import { Card } from 'components/Card';
import { localDateTime, dateFilter } from 'helpers';

const red = '#644DFF';
const purple = '#F73F64';

const DailyTrafficCard = (props) => {
  const { store, capacity, data, setVar} = props;

  const lastSevenDays = Array(7)
    .fill()
    .map((_, i) => {
      const localdate = localDateTime(store);
      return localdate()
        .subtract(i, 'day')
        .format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]07:00:00[Z]');
    });
  //console.log('lastSevenDays',lastSevenDays);
  let chart1;
  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = document && document.querySelector('#daily-traffic-chart');
    if (!ctx) {
      return;
    }
    chart1 = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
          data: data[0],
          barThickness: 13,
          backgroundColor: (ctx) => {
            const idx = ctx && ctx.dataIndex;
            const val = ctx && ctx.dataset && ctx.dataset.data && ctx.dataset.data[idx];
            return val < 40 ? purple : red;
          }
        }]
      },
      options: {
        //events:[],
        intersect: false,
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            offset: true,
            time: {
              unit: 'hour',
              displayFormats: {
                hour: 'HH',
              },
            },
            ticks: {autoSkip: false,
            },
            gridLines: {
              display: false,
            },
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              display: true,
            },
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: false,
              max: capacity,
              stepSize: 5
            },
          }],
        },
      }
    });
    if (chart1){
      chart1.destroy();
    }
  }, [data,capacity]);

  const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    setVar(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <Card
      classname="DailyTrafficCard"
      icon={<span><i className="icon-user"/></span>}
      title={<h3>Daily Traffic Analytics</h3>}>
      <div className="daily">
        <div className="daily-head p-4 text-center">
          <select className="py-2 px-3" onChange={handleOnChange}>
            {lastSevenDays.map(date => (
              <option key={date} value={date}>{dateFilter(date, 'dddd')}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>

        <div className="px-8">
          {data && data.length > 0 && (
            <canvas width="250" id="daily-traffic-chart"></canvas>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for this https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state

Comment: I'm not sure what your use case is, but it almost feel like useEffect is not the hook you want. You probably don't want any hook.  Just receive the `ctx` as a prop and create it directly w/o any hook

Answer (score 0):

If you want a variable to impact your view, it either need to ne a prop or a state. I don't know about Chart but I suppose you could store your chat in a state :

`const [myChart, setMyChart] = useState();`

And in your `useEffect` you set it with your chart, and when destroying it you just set it with what you want, either what `destroy()` returns, if it does return something (I don't know about it), or null, undefined, etc. as you wish.